# Attempting to create a button that toggles Display between none and block, only works once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a banner on my page that is fairly extensive in size, so I wanted to offer the user the ability to toggle its visibility (using the Display property/attribute). I have the button working to set the Display: none but it fails to set it back to Display: block upon more clicking. Code snippets:

CSS:

```
.banner-row {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" onclick="toggleBanner()"><span class="dx-icon-collapse icon"></span></button>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        function toggleBanner() {
            if (document.getElementById("banner-row").style.display = "block") {
                document.getElementById("banner-row").style.display = "none";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("banner-row").style.display = "none") {
                document.getElementById("banner-row").style.display = "block"
            }
        }
</script>
```

I hope that what I'm asking is possible, and sorry for any stupid mistakes on my part! Still learning all of this stuff.

Comment: `=` assigns the value. You should be using `===` to compare values. Also, you can not read CSS with `.style`. You would need to use `.getComputedStyle`.

Comment: In your CSS, you are targeting a class, in your Javascript your are targeting an id.

Comment: check the `if` and `else if` conditions you are doing `=` instead of `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

1) You are trying to the set the style of an element with an `id` in the HTML but which is a `class` in the CSS.

2) You are assigning (`=`) values in your `if/else` condition rather than [doing a comparison (`==` or `===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

3) You are checking the *inline* style and, initially, the banner doesn't have one so `display` is empty. You can either check for that like I've done below, or use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```js
// Cache the element so you don't repeat yourself
const banner = document.getElementById("banner-row");

function toggleBanner() {
  if (banner.style.display === "block" || banner.style.display === '') {
    banner.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    banner.style.display = "block"
  }
}
```

```css
#banner-row {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-row">BANNER</div>
<button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" onclick="toggleBanner()">Click</button>
```

Comment: My apologies for my mistakes :( But thank you so much for the help, this makes a lot of sense and I love the tidiness of the const. I've never dealt with JS/css/html before and been given a huge project with a tight deadline, so I feel a little rushed, hence why I forgot to include the banner-row html which did already have the ID set appropriately. Thank you again :)

Comment: @Ubi, it's worth checking out Gerard's answer too.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a class to hide the banner, all you need in JS is a simple toggle of the class list.

```js
const banner = document.getElementById("banner-row");
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

toggleBanner = () => banner.classList.toggle("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="banner-row">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" onclick="toggleBanner()">
  <span class="dx-icon-collapse icon"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use == instead of = in your if and else if conditions. == is the comparison operator in JavaScript and = is used for assigning values.